# Reactive Extension in msword

Tags: ms-word, vsto, system.reactive

I am wondering if it is possible to use Reactive Extensions in Word. I have seen this where Jeff shows how to wire up a workbook open event in excel http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/rx/thread/5ace45b1-778b-4ddd-b2ab-d5c8a1659f5f.

I wondering if I could do the same sort of thing in word.

I have got this far....

```
     public static class ApplicationExtensions
  {
    public static IObservable<Word.Document> DocumentBeforeSaveAsObservable(this Word.Application application)
    {
      return Observable.Create<Word.Document>(observer =>
      {
        Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler handler = observer.OnNext;
        application.DocumentBeforeSave += handler;

        return () => application.DocumentBeforeSave -= handler;
      });
    }
  }
```

but I receive the error No overload for 'OnNext' matches delegate 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Regards

Mike

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is an issue of delegate signatures.

[`IObserver<T>.OnNext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd782792.aspx) is defined as `void (T value)`

whereas [`ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_documentbeforesaveeventhandler%28office.11%29.aspx) is defined as `void (Document doc, ref bool SaveAsUI, ref bool Cancel)`

If you only need to emit the `Document` (and not the other details, like making it cancelable), you can do something like this:

```
public static IObservable<Word.Document> DocumentBeforeSaveAsObservable(
    this Word.Application application)
{
    return Observable.Create<Word.Document>(observer =>
    {
        Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler handler = 
            (doc, ref saveAsUI, ref cancel) => observer.OnNext(doc);

        application.DocumentBeforeSave += handler;

        return () => application.DocumentBeforeSave -= handler;
    });
}
```

If you do require all the data, you'll need to create a wrapper class of some kind an `IObservable` sequence can only emit a single type:

```
public class DocumentBeforeSaveEventArgs : CancelEventArgs
{
    public Document Document { get; private set; }
    public bool SaveAsUI { get; private set; }

    public DocumentBeforeSaveEventArgs(Document document, bool saveAsUI)
    {
        this.Document = document;
        this.SaveAsUI = saveAsUI;
    }
}
```

And then you can use it like so:

```
public static IObservable<Word.Document> DocumentBeforeSaveAsObservable(
    this Word.Application application)
{
    return Observable.Create<Word.Document>(observer =>
    {
        Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler handler = 
            (doc, ref saveAsUI, ref cancel) => 
            {
                var args = new DocumentBeforeSaveEventArgs(doc, saveAsUI);

                observer.OnNext(args);

                cancel = args.Cancel;
            };

        application.DocumentBeforeSave += handler;

        return () => application.DocumentBeforeSave -= handler;
    });
}
```